# Caching through a cronjob

Tags: php, caching, cron

So here's the deal,

By using JustinTV's api and a bit of PHP i made a really simple script that checks if certain players are streaming at the moment. After implementating it on my site i found out it took ages to load (which is actually expected). So i read a bit about this cronjob thing and thought it was probably the way to solve it.

So, resuming, i want to create a cronjob that runs that script, checks if those players are streaming and then save it in cache. That being said, i want to create a widget for Wordpress that uses that cache and places the saved data there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to save the information from the cron job in the Wordpress database. This will allow you access it later from another page. See this page for more details (option 4 is likely most suitable): https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Saving_Plugin_Data_to_the_Database

Comment: I find your answer pretty useful, but does that require i make a plugin? 

 Would a possible solution be running the cronjob and making the script create a .html file (and rewrite it everytime the cronjob cycles). Then summon that .html in a widget?

Comment: You should be able to run a cron job without making a plugin. However, writing to an HTML file would not only be insecure, but would also be very inefficient. You should instead save the information in the database.

Comment: Then ill read about the db management in Wordpress. Thanks for your time!